# How to add a few minutes or days to the date and time String?

Tags: java, datetime

Given that, i have a string like `String addTimestamp = 2021-05-01T00:00:00+02:00`, I wish to add a few minutes or days to his date.

My current solution for adding 3 more days is:

```
ZonedDateTime result = ZonedDateTime.parse(addTimestamp, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);

String removeTimestamp = result.plusDays(3).toString();
System.out.println("addTimestamp:    " + addTimestamp);
System.out.println("removeTimestamp: " + removeTimestamp);
```

This works well, but the it breaks the format:

```
addTimestamp:    2021-05-01T00:00:00+02:00
removeTimestamp: 2021-05-04T00:00+02:00
```

As you see, the seconds in the `removeTimestamp` are missed. How can i fix it?

Comment: You can specify the formatter you want to use for formatting, instead of just calling `toString()`.

Comment: You format it back to string with the desired pattern `String removeTimestamp = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(result.plusdays(3));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to format the `ZonedDateTime` to the correct format. Just calling toString() on it will yield undesired results:

You can use the `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` of DateTimeFormatter, which you used for parsing, also use it for formatting back to string:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

```
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `format()` method on `ZonedDateTime` directly:

```
result.plusDays(3).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
```